# Need help finishing my ATM machine

Tags: c

Its for my programming class in C,its a simple ATM that does 4 actions:
Withdraw,Deposit,Acc details,check user balance, and exit.I have made the simple base of it, but due to a change in the project requirements i now need to place a password factor into it, i have tried and have come up with the following code,but i want to make it so its asks for the password before the mainmenu i.e:deposit,withdraw etc... i have also tried using switch case but i felt that didn't change anything.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code so far that has been done by me is :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
  int atmfun();
 main()
 {
 int option1;
 do
 option1=atmfun();
  while (option1==1);

  getch();
  }

  int atmfun()
  {


  char Name1[]="Fever";
  char Name2[]="JACK";
  char Name3[]="JOHN";
  char choice='y',choice1='n';
  char FullName1[]="Fever tyrell";
  char FullName2[]="Jack williams";
  char FullName3[]="John Mason";
  int i,a,AccBalance = 20000;
  int acc_type,password,option,option1;
  int passworda=31081;
  int passwordb=12345;
  int passwordc=12456;
  int w_amount,d_amount;
  printf("Welcome to generic ATM\n");
  printf("\n\nPlease choose an option...");
  printf("\n(1)View account details.");
  printf("\n(2)Check balance.");
  printf("\n(3)Withdraw amount.");
  printf("\n(4)Deposit amount.");
  printf("\n(5)Exit.\n");
  scanf("\n%d",&option);



                //start of option 1
                if(option==1) //if user wants to view their account details
                {
                    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR PASSWORD:  ");
                    scanf("%d",&password);          

                if 
            (password!=passworda&&password!=passwordb&&password!=passwordc)

                    printf("YOU HAVE ENTERED AN INVALID PASSWORD");
                else
                if(password==passworda)
                {
                    printf("WELCOME Mr.%s\n\n",Name1);
                    //rest of the account details
                }
                else 
                if(password==passwordb) 
                {
                    printf("WELCOME Mr.%s\n\n",Name2);
                    //rest of the acc details
                }
                else 
                if(password==passwordc) 
                {
                    printf("WELCOME Mr.%s\n\n",Name3);
                    //rest of the acc details
                }   
                {
                    printf("\nDo you wish to go back to the main menu?\nEnter 1 for YES, and any other number for NO\n");
                    scanf("%d",&option1);
                if (option1==1)
                {
                return option1;
                }
                else 
                    printf("Thank you for using Generic ATM");
                return 0;
                }
                }
                // end of option1

                // start of option 2
                if(option==2) // if user wants to view his account balance
                    {
                    printf("Your account balance is $%d",AccBalance);

                    printf("\nDo you wish to go back to the main menu? \nEnter 1 for YES, and any other number for NO\n");
                    scanf("%d",&option1);
                if (option1==1)
                {
                return option1;
                }
                else 
                    printf("Thank you for using Generic ATM");
                return 0;
                }

                //end of option 2


                //start of option 3
                if(option==3)// if user wants to withdraw money
                {
                    printf("Enter amount to withdraw\n$");
                    scanf("%d",&w_amount);
                {
                if(w_amount<=0)
                {
                    printf("Amount cannot be a number under zero or zero");
                    for(i=4;i>0;i--)
                {
                    printf("\nEnter appropriate amount,you have %d tries  left\n",i);
                {
                    printf("Enter amount to withdraw\n$");
                    scanf("%d",&w_amount);
                if(w_amount<=0)
                {
                    printf("You cannot withdraw this amount");
                }
                }
                if (i==1)
                    printf("\nYou have exceeded your tries\n");
                }
                }
                else 
                if(w_amount>AccBalance)
                {
                    printf("You don't have sufficient funds, please enter the amount within your Account Balance");
                    for(i=4;i>0;i--)
                {
                    printf("\nEnter appropriate amount,you have %d tries left\n",i);
                {
                    printf("Enter amount to withdraw\n$");
                    scanf("%d",&w_amount);
                if(w_amount<=0)
                {
                    printf("You cannot withdraw this amount");
                }
                }
                if (i==1)

                    printf("\nYou have exceeded your tries\n");

                }
                }
                else
                {
                    AccBalance=AccBalance-w_amount;
                    printf("Your new balance is $%d",AccBalance);
                }
                }
                printf("\nDo you wish to go back to the main menu?\nEnter 1for YES, and any other number for NO\n");

                scanf("%d",&option1);
                if (option1==1)
                {
                return option1;
                }
                else 
                    printf("Thank you for using Generic ATM");
                return 0;
                }
                //end of option 3

                //start of option 4
                if (option==4) // if user wants to deposit dem moneys bbby
                {
                    printf("Enter amount to deposit\n$");
                    scanf("%d",&d_amount);
                if(d_amount<=0)
                {
                    printf("You cannot deposit this amount");
                for(i=4;i>0;i--)
                {
                    printf("\nEnter appropriate amount,you have %d tries left\n",i);
                {
                    printf("Enter amount to deposit\n$");
                    scanf("%d",&d_amount);
                if(d_amount<=0)
                {
                    printf("You cannot deposit this amount");
                }
                }
                if (i==1)
                    printf("\nYou have exceeded your tries\n");
                }
                }
                else 
                {
                    AccBalance=AccBalance+d_amount;
                    printf("You have deposited $%d",d_amount);
                    printf("\nYour New balance is $%d",AccBalance);
                }
                printf("\nDo you wish to go back to the main menu?\nEnter 1 for YES, and any other number for NO\n");
                    scanf("%d",&option1);
                if (option1==1)
                {
                return option1;
                }
                else 
                    printf("Thank you for using Generic ATM");
                return 0;
                }
                //end of option 4

                //start of option 5
                {
                if (option == 5);
                    printf("\nThank you for using Generic ATM\n");
                    return option;
                }
                //end of option 5
return 0;

getch();
}
```

Comment: oh my word.... sorry but its an error in formatting, printf seems to go to a new line,

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: Additionally....Not sure if it is an issues but.... since you use integers, no passwords can have leading 0's in them.  The numeric value password 00005 is the same as 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(){
  while true{
    if (checkPassword()) handleTransaction();
  };
};
```

See how easy it is if you don't do everything in main?

Comment: I don't quite understand, i'm really new can you please explain what you have done here.What is checkpassword here.

Comment: `if checkPassword() returns 1
then
call handleTransaction()`  where `checkPassword` would be a function returning 1 if the password is correct and `handleTransaction` a function which would do all the stuff.

Comment: So i just make a function called check pass, then if it returns 1 call handletrans, which is the rest of the program right ? ...

Comment: ^^ yes.  Keeps main() for just the overall process logic.

Answer (score 0):

To ask password before main menu you have to ask before print(main menu):

```
//rest of code
printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR PASSWORD:  ");

do{
        scanf("%d",&password);
        if(password!=passworda&&password!=passwordb&&password!=passwordc)
             printf("YOU HAVE ENTERED AN INVALID PASSWORD");
        else break;
  }while(true);

if(password==passworda)
{
        printf("WELCOME Mr.%s\n\n",Name1);
                    //rest of the account details
}
else
     if(password==passwordb)
     {
            printf("WELCOME Mr.%s\n\n",Name2);
                    //rest of the acc details
     }
     else
          if(password==passwordc)
          {
               printf("WELCOME Mr.%s\n\n",Name3);
                    //rest of the acc details
          }

  printf("Welcome to generic ATM\n");
  printf("\n\nPlease choose an option...");
  printf("\n(1)View account details.");
  printf("\n(2)Check balance.");
  printf("\n(3)Withdraw amount.");
  printf("\n(4)Deposit amount.");
  printf("\n(5)Exit.\n");
  scanf("\n%d",&option);

//rest of code
```